# Cannot set the Title-property of a page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a weird problem in asp.net.

I have a page in which I can't set the `Title`-property under some circumstances.
If I set the `Title`-property to a string-value in Page_PreLoad, then the value is empty. However this happens only in some circumstances, I don't understand really when.

If I set a breakpoint and look with the debugger, after setting `Title="test";`, the Title property is empty. However the PageTitle in the browser shows "test". If I use the Title-property in the markup of the page, it is empty. Is there some special magic with the Title-property, I have to know about?

Comment: Are you setting it in the masterpage or the page?

Comment: @Patricker: No, however I set it in OnPagePreInit of the base-class to some generic value based on the navigation. However this happens for all pages but the problem arises only in one page. Is this ilegal, to change the value of the Title-property during page-lifetime? Maybe this is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Page.Title property is a wrapper around the HtmlHead control, which is exposed through Page.Header.  Before the header gets initialized, it stores the title in a property until it gets initialized.  Whenever the Header gets established, it copies this property over... That may be what the issue is, or maybe its something else...

HTH.